# Need to select distinct dates for year 2019 and Count

Tags: mysql

This query doesn't work as soon as I give a date range.It works fine when it it like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT (receive_date) ,(SELECT COUNT(receive_date) from stocks WHERE receive_date = Count.receive_date) as `count` from stocks as Count ORDER BY receive_date DESC
```

But I need to select distinct dates  only for the year 2019

```
SELECT DISTINCT (receive_date) 
from stocks 
WHERE receive_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31',
(SELECT COUNT(receive_date) from stocks WHERE receive_date = Count.receive_date) as `count` from stocks as Count 
ORDER BY receive_date DESC
```

Error

Static analysis:

4 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 144)
>       Unexpected token. (near "count" at position 147)
>       This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "from" at position 155)
>       Unrecognized statement type. (near "from" at position 155)

SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT DISTINCT (receive_date) from stocks WHERE receive_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31',(SELECT COUNT(receive_date) from stocks WHERE receive_date = Count.receive_date) as `count` from stocks as Count ORDER BY receive_date DESC
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(receive_date) from stocks WHERE rdate = Count.receive_date) as `count` from stocks' at line 1

Comment: Move the WHERE clause before ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch distinct `receive_date` and their count, you can just use `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT 
    receive_date, 
    COUNT(0) AS cnt 
FROM stocks 
WHERE receive_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY receive_date
ORDER BY receive_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple syntactical errors in your code.
The order of the clauses WHERE and FROM for example are totally wrong.
Also you don't use subquery and the aliases correctly.
 
As for the logic I believe that this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT receive_date, COUNT(*) as `count` 
FROM stocks
WHERE receive_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
GROUP BY receive_date
ORDER BY receive_date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the support pal :)